# Atualizar tabela mysql com imagem

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer o upload de uma imagem porém a tabela não é atualizada. já `utilizei var_dump($arquivo)` e o retorno é correto, com o nome do arquivo + extensão.

o código esta no header da minha pagina e o form não possui action, quando eu clico em enviar a pagina é recarregada e o `var_dump($arquivo)` e o `var_dump($linha)` mostram os resultados normalmente porém a atualização na tabela não é executada.

O código que estou usando é:

```
$buscartexto = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM institucional WHERE id =:id");
$buscartexto->bindValue(":id", $id);
$buscartexto->execute();
$linha = $buscartexto->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['texto'])){

$data = trim($_POST['data']);
$titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
$texto = trim($_POST['texto']);
$caminho = 'uploads/';

$nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"]; 
$tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"];
$nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"];
$arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
$extensao = end($arquivoArray);
$arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

if(move_uploaded_file($nomeArquivo, $arquivo)){
$atualizartexto = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE institucional SET data =:data, titulo =:titulo, texto =:texto, imagem =:imagem WHERE id =:id");
$atualizartexto->bindValue("id", $id);
$atualizartexto->bindValue(":data", $data);
$atualizartexto->bindValue(":titulo", $titulo);
$atualizartexto->bindValue(":texto", $texto);
$atualizartexto->bindValue(":imagem", $arquivo);
$atualizartexto->execute();

if ($atualizartexto->rowCount() > 0) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Texto atualizado com sucesso!</div>';
}
else {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Texto não foi atualizado!    </div>';
}
}
}
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Não apareceu nada, eu consigo armazenar as 2 variaveis só que elas não fazem o update e o arquivo também não é movido para a pasta uploads.

Comment: Mas aparece texto não atualizado?

Comment: também não, eu acho que o código "morre" ali no `if(move_uploaded_file($nomeArquivo, $arquivo))`

Comment: hehehe tem que testar por partes agora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está no caminho da imagem... Então faça da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$buscartexto = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM institucional WHERE id =:id");
$buscartexto->bindValue(":id", $id);
$buscartexto->execute();
$linha = $buscartexto->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['texto'])){

    $data = trim($_POST['data']);
    $titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
    $texto = trim($_POST['texto']);
    $caminho = 'uploads/';

    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"]; 
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"];
    $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
    $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
    $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

    if(!is_dir($caminho)){
        mkdir($caminho, 0777);
        chmod($caminho, 0777);
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"], $arquivo)){
        $atualizartexto = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE institucional SET data =:data, titulo =:titulo, texto =:texto, imagem =:imagem WHERE id =:id");
        $atualizartexto->bindValue("id", $id);
        $atualizartexto->bindValue(":data", $data);
        $atualizartexto->bindValue(":titulo", $titulo);
        $atualizartexto->bindValue(":texto", $texto);
        $atualizartexto->bindValue(":imagem", $arquivo);
        $atualizartexto->execute();

        if ($atualizartexto->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Texto atualizado com sucesso!</div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Texto não foi atualizado!    </div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "O arquivo não foi enviado.";  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: funcionou 100%.